# Multiple-File Template Implementation

Tags: c++, templates

With normal functions, the declaration and definition are often separated across multiple files like so:

```
// Foo.h

namespace Foo
{
    void Bar();
}
```

.

```
// Foo.cpp

#include "Foo.h"

void Foo::Bar()
{
    cout << "Inside function." << endl;
}
```

It is my understanding that this **cannot** be done with templates.  The declaration and definition must not be separate because the appropriate form of the template is created "on-demand" when needed.

So, how and where are templates typically defined in a multiple-file project like this?  My intuition is that it would be in `Foo.cpp` because that's where the "meat" of functions normally is, but on the other hand it's the header file that's going to be included.

Comment: Can't put it in `Foo.cpp`, because then it's only seen when building `Foo.o`.  You could put it in `Foo_inst.h`, which includes `Foo.h` and is included by anything that needs the templates defined, not just declared... which you quickly see is almost anything that includes `Foo.h`, so there's not really any point in keeping them separate.  The good news is that modern linkers can recognize that a function is an instantiation of template code in multiple `.o` files and won't die with a "multiple definition" error, but instead will pick one and link everything to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template code stays in the `.hh` file.  There's no reason to make them separate files, though it is good practice to put the definitions after *all* the declarations.

When the compiler generates template code, it flags it so that the linker knows that the instantiation of a template in one compilation unit (i.e. `.o` file) is the exact same code as one in another unit.  It will keep one and discard the rest, rather than bailing out with a "multiply defined symbol" error.

This is true of modern compilers with good template support.  In the case of GCC, since 2.8.  (I know, I wrote a lot of code for gcc 2.7.2.2 before they smartened the linker up and you had to jump through hoops to make templates build right.)

Comment: The reason to keep them separate is the same reason we're using forward declarations: You present the compiler with just as much code as it needs, to speed up the compilation. If a class A declares a template class as a member in A.hpp, it doesn't need to know the implementations of any methods yet. Neither does anyone including A.hpp. It's sufficient to include the implementations in A.cpp, were their actually needed.

Comment: Honestly, I think that the simplification of "just put it all in the header file and let the compiler figure it out" is worth avoiding the hidden bugs of implementing the separation method incorrectly. In your example, if a forward declaration is all that's needed, then it `A.hpp` should make the forward declaration and be done with it. That never works in my practice, because there's always some inline code or another in `A.hpp` that needs to operate on the template object, so the implementation has to be pulled in as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write definitions of templated methods in a .hxx file and include it at the end of your header file (.hh) in which you declare it. The .cc/.cpp is used to define non-templated methods.

So you'll have one .hh, one .hxx (included at the end of the .hh), and one .cc; so that including your templated class header file will include its definition too.

Example:

```
// list.hh
#IFNDEF LIST_HH
# DEFINE LIST_HH

template <typename T>
class List
{
  void fun1(T a);

  void fun2();
}

# include "list.hxx"

#ENDIF

// list.hxx
#IFNDEF LIST_HXX
# DEFINE LIST_HXX

# include "list.hh"

template <typename T>
void List::fun1(T a)
{
   // ...
}

#ENDIF

// list.cc

#include "list.hh"

void List::fun2()
{
   // ...
}


// anywhere.cc

#include "list.hh"

// ...
```

**EDIT**

There are several strategies to compile templates. The most common strategy is the one described above to let every user of the class template instantiate the code.

But, because the *.hh file includes the *.hxx file, each time a simple declaration of a template is needed, the full implementation comes with it. And if the implementation requires other declarations such as std::string, you force all the client code to parse the string header.

To avoid instantiations several times (time and space consuming), you can introduce a fourth type of file, *.hcc: files that must be compiled once for each concrete template parameter.

[See Also Compile-Time Dependencies](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/007.htm)

**EDIT2**

Writing the template definition directly in the header file is called **inclusion model**. Doing so increases the cost of including the header. Not only because we added the definition of the template but because we included headers (, , whatever) which represent thousands of lines. **A real problem for significant programs to compile (we are talking about hours of compilation here)**.
The **separation model**

[Source](http://www.drdobbs.com/184403945)

And my last argument: keep clear the header file so that it only contains the class declaration and its documentation. Like that, any other programmer is able to fastly read your header file: what is the public interface of this class, what does the documentation says.

Comment: I don't see any point in splitting them between `.hh` and `.hxx` files since, if you pull in one, you always get both.  May as well keep them together.

Comment: Why can methods be defined in separate files, but standalone functions cannot?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what exact template instantiations it needs until it's compiling the code.  Also, C++ compilers are designed to not know of other source files in the project; that's why we have "include files" at all.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone @Maxpm see my edits, this is related to compile-time optimization

Comment: @Julio: I'm still not seeing the point.  The way you have things set up, `#include "list.hh"` gets you `list.hh` followed by `list.hxx`, and `#include "list.hxx"` gets you `list.hh` followed by `list.hxx` as well.  Everything could be in `list.hh` and you'd get the exact same thing.  And I don't see what you're optimizing at compile time (the usual definition of "compile-time optimization") though it looks like you're trying to give the compiler less to compile (i.e. "optimizing compile time"), but to do that you'd need to remove the `#include "list.hxx"`.

Comment: @Julio: Re: Edit2, conclusion 2 of the source you cite is "Usually, you should use the inclusion model (that is, put all template code in header files)", which was my answer above. The article cites the inclusion model (6.1.2), explicit instantiation (6.2.1, which requires you to declare what template instances need to be emitted, which is a major pain on large projects), a combination of those (6.2.2), and the export keyword (6.3, covered in ybungalobill's answer), none of which look like your answer.  I'm still not seeing the point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm disappointed that no answers mentioned that the C++ standard **permits** you to separate the definition from the declaration. It goes like this:

```
// Foo.h
export template<class T> T f();
```

```
// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"

export template<class T> T f()
{
    // blah blah
}
```

Unfortunately, almost no compilers support *export*. Comeau is one that does.

However, *export* is removed from C++ in C++0x.

Comment: Which C++ standard was that in?  This is almost Zen: if a standard allows something clever, but compilers don't implement it, is the technique valid?

Comment: @Mike: The problem is that it's too complicated to implement using traditional compiler/linker toolchain, so all major vendors banned it. We have smart compilers and dumb linkers, it ought to be the other way around. Note that traditional compilers doesn't check ODR violation, still it's forbidden by the standard (yeah, no diagnostics required, blah blah).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  And re: dumb compilers and smart linkers: I think that's where the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) project went.  They compile to a virtual machine bytecode, then link, optimize, and translate to machine code.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised everyone completely missed the Generic Type approach.  In effect leveraging unique Type placeholder.

### Caveat

If you understand the behavior of the Linker/Compiler, you need prepare and plan for those consequences.

Probably a good idea to FirstLetter Generalize the Placeholder so it is completely unique (i.e. `template <typename OMT>` and `template <typename OLT>`)

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void OutputMessage ( T msg ) {
    std::cout << msg;
}

template <typename C>
void OutputLine ( C msg ) {
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    OutputLine("Yello Horld");
    OutputMessage("Wello Horld!\n");
}
```