# Using Template Member data

Tags: c++

I was trying to use a template based class as a member of another class. This other class will decide based on its data member value what is the data type that the template based member should use. To this end I used bit of polymorphism to decide on run time the instantiation.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class templateDynamic : public Base
{
public:
    templateDynamic();
    ~templateDynamic();
    void print();
};

    template <typename T>
templateDynamic<T>::templateDynamic()
{
}

template <typename T>
templateDynamic<T>::~templateDynamic()
{
}

template <typename T>
void templateDynamic<T>::print()
{

}

class Holder
{
private:
    Base * m_ABC;
public:
    Holder(int a);  
    void print();
};

void Holder::print()
{
    m_ABC->print();
}

Holder::Holder(int a)
{
    if(a == 1)
      m_ABC = new templateDynamic<int>();
    else
      m_ABC = new templateDynamic<float>();
}

int main()
{
    Holder aHolder(1);
    aHolder.print();
    Holder aHolder2(2);
    aHolder.print();
}
```

Print function will then print based on the type of T is it an int or float.
I am getting a linker error at this point.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   templateDynamic::templateDynamic(void)"
>   (??0?$templateDynamic@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public:
>   __thiscall Holder::Holder(void)" (??0Holder@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple-File Template Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496440/multiple-file-template-implementation)

Comment: Well, but there is no implementation of `templateDynamic` ctor, why is the error unexpected?

Comment: Iow where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined the constructor for `templateDynamic` and `Holder`

Comment: that was not the reason. I had this implementation. Just left out in the sample posted. My  bad

Comment: @surega: you defined `Holder::Holder(int a)` but your class has `Holder::Holder()`.  You need to change one or the other.